# Spring Security: Unsecured Basic Authentication

Tags: java, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot Application, and in the process of learning Spring Security.
Spring Boot 3.1.5, Java 17

I have configured Spring Security and it works.

There is a few issues I wonder why it is working the way it does.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private static final String[] ENDPOINTS = { "/api/first/**", "/api/second/**" };

    private static final String ROLE = "USER";

    private final String username;

    private final String password;

    public SecurityConfig(
        @Value("${spring.security.user.name}") final String username,
        @Value("${spring.security.user.password}") final String password
    ) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService(final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        final UserDetails anyUser = User.builder()
            .username(username)
            .password(passwordEncoder.encode(password))
            .roles(ROLE)
            .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(anyUser);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.securityMatcher(ENDPOINTS)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(createRequestMatchers())
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @NotNull
    private Customizer<AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry> createRequestMatchers() {
        return (authz) ->
            authz.requestMatchers(ENDPOINTS).authenticated();
    }
}
```

When accessing the APIs I can see that it is authenticating the user when calling the API /api/second?id=7324325

```
2023-12-01T07:59:05.955+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] t.r.a.t.MyApplication : Starting MyApplication using Java 21.0.1 with PID 5548 (C:\Users\djviking\workspace-company\java-my-application\target\classes started by djviking in C:\Users\djviking\workspace-company\java-my-application)
2023-12-01T07:59:05.956+01:00 DEBUG 5548 --- [           main] t.r.a.t.MyApplication : Running with Spring Boot v3.1.5, Spring v6.0.13
2023-12-01T07:59:05.956+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] t.r.a.t.MyApplication : The following 1 profile is active: "test"
2023-12-01T07:59:06.535+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-12-01T07:59:06.669+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 124 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-12-01T07:59:06.966+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2023-12-01T07:59:06.974+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2023-12-01T07:59:07.429+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8306 (http)
2023-12-01T07:59:07.436+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-12-01T07:59:07.437+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.15]
2023-12-01T07:59:07.519+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-12-01T07:59:07.519+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1525 ms
Standard Commons Logging discovery in action with spring-jcl: please remove commons-logging.jar from classpath in order to avoid potential conflicts
2023-12-01T07:59:07.715+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-12-01T07:59:07.752+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.13.Final
2023-12-01T07:59:07.754+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-12-01T07:59:07.829+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] o.h.e.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl    : Envers integration enabled? : true
2023-12-01T07:59:07.951+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-12-01T07:59:07.968+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-12-01T07:59:08.475+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: f46ed47e-63af-407b-b0c8-cfee5a773ff8
2023-12-01T07:59:08.476+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-12-01T07:59:08.494+01:00  WARN 5548 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: SQLServer2012Dialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
2023-12-01T07:59:08.495+01:00  WARN 5548 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000026: SQLServer2012Dialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect instead
2023-12-01T07:59:09.377+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2023-12-01T07:59:10.208+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-12-01T07:59:10.767+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] o.s.d.j.r.query.QueryEnhancerFactory     : Hibernate is in classpath; If applicable, HQL parser will be used.
2023-12-01T07:59:11.312+01:00  WARN 5548 --- [           main] i.l.graphql.generator.OperationMapper    : Potential type name collision detected: Int bound to multiple types: java.lang.Integer and int. Assign unique names using the appropriate annotations or override the TypeInfoGenerator. For details and solutions see https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr/wiki/Errors#non-unique-type-name
2023-12-01T07:59:11.465+01:00  WARN 5548 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-12-01T07:59:11.871+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Or [Mvc [pattern='/api/first/**'], Mvc [pattern='/api/second/**']] with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@67a84d80, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@21d297a, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@7445fdb2, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@56ed0511, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5db553f9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@495590a7, com.company.raavare.avregning.tilleggtrekk.config.SecurityConfig$HeaderFilter@7879348, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@35069061, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5199d74e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6b869242, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@2afee2ee, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@77ad33c]
2023-12-01T07:59:12.224+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2023-12-01T07:59:12.224+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'my-application.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2023-12-01T07:59:12.225+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2023-12-01T07:59:12.248+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8306 (http) with context path ''
2023-12-01T07:59:12.301+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8088 (http)
2023-12-01T07:59:12.301+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-12-01T07:59:12.302+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.15]
2023-12-01T07:59:12.327+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat-1].[localhost].[/]     : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-12-01T07:59:12.327+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 75 ms
Standard Commons Logging discovery in action with spring-jcl: please remove commons-logging.jar from classpath in order to avoid potential conflicts
2023-12-01T07:59:12.339+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2023-12-01T07:59:12.370+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8088 (http) with context path ''
2023-12-01T07:59:12.377+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [           main] t.r.a.t.MyApplication : Started MyApplication in 6.738 seconds (process running for 7.222)
2023-12-01T07:59:20.608+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [nio-8306-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-12-01T07:59:20.609+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [nio-8306-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-12-01T07:59:20.610+01:00  INFO 5548 --- [nio-8306-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-12-01T07:59:20.623+01:00 DEBUG 5548 --- [nio-8306-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/second?id=7324325
2023-12-01T07:59:20.757+01:00 DEBUG 5548 --- [nio-8306-exec-3] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authenticated user
2023-12-01T07:59:20.760+01:00 DEBUG 5548 --- [nio-8306-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=username, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
2023-12-01T07:59:20.768+01:00 DEBUG 5548 --- [nio-8306-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /api/second?id=7324325
2023-12-01T07:59:20.782+01:00 DEBUG 5548 --- [nio-8306-exec-3] .r.a.t.w.MyApplicationController : Get Result for Id Id=7324325
```

I have a third API "/api/third", that is not configured in the SecurityConfig.

When calling this /api/third, it does not log from Spring Security, as it did for the /api/second. Does that mean that the third API is unsecured?

If I add Security configuration for the third API in SpringSecurity:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.securityMatcher(ENDPOINTS).authorizeHttpRequests(createRequestMatchers())   
            .securityMatcher("/api/third/**").authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz.requestMatchers("/api/third/**").hasRole("ADMIN"))
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
```

When I call the second API this time, it does not log Spring Security like it did before.

Now when I call the third API, with the User (who is not Admin role), then it logs Security.

```
2023-12-01T08:11:42.857+01:00  INFO 24016 --- [           main] t.r.a.t.MyApplication                    : Started MyApplication in 6.072 seconds (process running for 6.54)
2023-12-01T08:12:09.529+01:00  INFO 24016 --- [nio-8306-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-12-01T08:12:09.530+01:00  INFO 24016 --- [nio-8306-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-12-01T08:12:09.531+01:00  INFO 24016 --- [nio-8306-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-12-01T08:12:09.560+01:00 DEBUG 24016 --- [nio-8306-exec-5] .r.a.t.w.MyApplicationController         : Get Result for Id Id=7324325
2023-12-01T08:12:24.736+01:00 DEBUG 24016 --- [nio-8306-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/third?id=7324325
2023-12-01T08:12:24.871+01:00 DEBUG 24016 --- [nio-8306-exec-8] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authenticated user
2023-12-01T08:12:24.872+01:00 DEBUG 24016 --- [nio-8306-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=username, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
2023-12-01T08:12:24.879+01:00 DEBUG 24016 --- [nio-8306-exec-8] o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl   : Responding with 403 status code
```

The log "Get Result for Id Id=7324325" is when me calling the /api/second

The log Securing GET is now only for the third API.

Comment: please update with debug logs for the others and we can explain exacctly what is happening.

Comment: debug logs from what others?

Comment: When you are accessing the other endpoints

Comment: There is no debug logging then.
Before I added the /api/third, I got the debug logging as above. When I added the /api/thid, it got the debug logging, but when I access the other, there was no logging.

Comment: What you are claiming makes no sense. Well no logs i cant help you, good luck

Comment: That is exactly why I am asking. When I added the third security configuration to HttpSecurity, the logs shows Secured Get for that API endpoint, but nothing for the first others.

Comment: well we usually dont ask for peoples opinions on logs, we prefer that you post your logs in full so that we get an ubiased full picture of what is happening in your server. So no, there are no logs good luck.

Comment: I am not asking about an opinion, but why Spring Security is behaving like it does in my example. Full logs coming up...

Comment: I didnt say you were asking for an opinion. I said we ask for logs so we can read them. We dont ask for someones intepretation of their logs.